# Facebook SDK for iOS: FBSDKShareDialog is not shown

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am a newbie in iOS, and I would like  to share a link using the Facebook SDK for iOS. My code's as follows:

```
@IBAction func shareVoucherUsingFacebook(sender: UIButton) {
    print("Facebook")
    let content : FBSDKShareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
    content.contentURL = NSURL(string: "www.google.com")
    content.contentTitle = "Content Title"
    content.contentDescription = "This is the description"

    let shareDialog: FBSDKShareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()

    shareDialog.shareContent = content
    shareDialog.delegate = self
    shareDialog.fromViewController = self
    shareDialog.show()

}
```

I have also implemented the `FBSDKSharingDelegate` methods, but I am not able to receive the share dialog when I press this button, and the method `func sharer(sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didFailWithError error: NSError!)` is being executed, which means something is going wrong, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you ever found a solution to this? I'm running into the same issue right now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

changing this line

```
content.contentURL = NSURL(string: "www.google.com")
```

into

```
content.contentURL = NSURL(string: "https:\\www.google.com")
```

worked with me

this is the delegate methods I used

```
func sharer(sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didCompleteWithResults results: [NSObject: AnyObject])
{
    print(results)
}

func sharer(sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didFailWithError error: NSError!)
{
    print("sharer NSError")
    print(error.description)
}

func sharerDidCancel(sharer: FBSDKSharing!)
{
    print("sharerDidCancel")
}
```

Comment: Swift can't recognize these methods as delegate's. Didn't find the solution to write correct translation of these ObjC methods into Swift

Answer (score 2):

Just remember to add `http://` to your `contentURL` if you are using  `NSURL(string:"")` in your code.

```
let content : FBSDKShareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
content.contentURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
content.contentTitle = "Content Title"
content.contentDescription = "This is the description"

FBSDKShareDialog.showFromViewController(self, withContent: content, delegate: self)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works absolutely fine for Swift4 as well

Answer (score 0):

implementing the delegate methods did the trick for me