# Facebook Deep Linking is not opening the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, deep-linking

I am sharing my post on Facebook. I am sharing Image, Content URL, Description. I am using this code for sharing:

```
FBSDKShareDialog *dialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
dialog.fromViewController = self;
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentTitle = APP_NAME;
content.contentDescription = text;
content.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[arrAllEvents valueForKey:@"flyer_image"]objectAtIndex:0]];
content.contentURL = url;
dialog.shareContent = content;
dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeFeedWeb;
[dialog show];
```

I have enable Deep Linking (News Feed links launch this app) option for https://developers.facebook.com.
I have added my Fbid and URLShema Like this

```
<key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>abcevent://</string>
                <string>fb1......</string>
            </array>
```

and add code in appdelegate.m for the same like this

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBSDKAppLinkUtility fetchDeferredAppLink:^(NSURL *url,NSError *error){
        if([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"abcevent"])
        {
            [self callNewsletter:url];
        }
    }];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];

}
```

Now if I am sharing my post on fb via application. That post click is not opening my app in iPhone Deep linking is not working.
Can anyone tell what other things I am missing with this?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643522/fbsdksharedialog-of-facebook-sdk-is-not-working-on-ios9 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33290566/facebook-sdk-for-ios-fbsdksharedialog-is-not-shown make sure you are passing proper URL.

Comment: it is not `<string>abcevent://</string>` it is `<string>abcevent</string>`

Comment: canyou show your plist

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik This is my Plist :=  https://imagebin.ca/v/3Pv0QBFGn4rL

Comment: @Niharika - are you changed the string or not

Comment: Yes i have changed but it is still same. Meanwhile i got this "https://stackoverflow.com/a/40745039/6271729" So do i need to implement branch.io for deeplinking?

Answer (score 0):

The `fetchDeferredAppLink` method only works with *ads*. It never worked with links shared organically on the News Feed. You can read about more limitations of deep linking from Facebook [in this blog post](https://blog.branch.io/deep-linking-from-facebook-in-2017/), but there are two core things to know:

1. Facebook has never supported deferred deep linking for non-paid content.
2. Facebook's App Links standard at one point supported normal deep linking (meaning if the app is already installed), but this has been broken on iOS for a long time.

If you want this sort of functionality, you'll need a separate solution like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team).